# change position and tittle tab "description and review" in product view

Tags: magento-1.9

how step detail if i want to change tittle and position tab description and review in product page magento 1.9.3 like this

before
[image]

after
[image]

Any suggestions please. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the file `app/frontend/design/{packageName}/{themeName}/layout/local.xml` if it does not exist already.

**Note:** `{packageName}` is most likely "***default***" or "***rwd***", depending on your site setup. `{themeName}` should be a folder you created to use as the theme for your site, which extends the "default" theme.

In that ***local.xml*** file, include the following: (If this file already exists for you, just add the contents within the '**catalog_product_view**' layout handle).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info"> 
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" before="-" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" >
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" after="product.attributes" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Description</value></action>
            </block>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" after="product.reviews" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Additional Information</value></action>
            </block>                                             
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

See the below the re-arrange tabs :

[image: default product page tabs order]

**After :**

[image: re-arrange product tabs on view page]